# SoundPlayer does not play sound first time it´s called

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've a really simple method for playing sound effects:

```
private void PlaySound(string file)
{
   var sp = new SoundPlayer(@"Effects\" + file + ".wav");
   sp.Play();
}
```

Then I do this to call it:

```
PlaySound("music");
```

Now, the first time `PlaySound("music")` gets called, it won't play it. The second time and all the other times after that it will.

Any ideas of what goes wrong here?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void PlaySound(string file){
   using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(@"Effects\" + file ' ".wav"))
    {
        // Use PlaySync to load and then play the sound.
        player.PlaySync();
    }
}
```

Why use PlaySync? If you just call the Play method in this program, the program will terminate before the sound plays. The Sync indicates that the program should pause while the sound plays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the [load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.load.aspx) method before playing.If the the file is not already loaded ,the file will be loaded with a call to [Play](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.play.aspx).Which explains why the file is not played the first time.

*If you call Play before the .wav file has been loaded into memory, the .wav file will be loaded before playback starts.*-MSDN

Both [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.load.aspx) and [PlaySync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playsync.aspx) will block the current thread.A better option would be to use the [LoadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.loadasync.aspx) to load the file asynchronously.

Comment: Does it have to the same SoundPlayer instance that load and plays the sound?

Comment: yes right.check this out http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/PlayingWavFiles.aspx.Read the section "Preloading Sounds Asynchronously"